Letting Typescript recognize new methods added through Object.prototype
I would like for typescript to recognize changes I make to the Object.prototype. Ideally, I would like to be able to do something like:
Object.prototype.l = function (title: string) => {
    console.log({[title]: this})
    return this
}
const bar = foo().l('bar')

The only downside is that typescript will show .l('bar') as an error. For context, my scripts tend to usually look something like this:
export function updateTaxRecord(context: updateTaxRecordContext): boolean {
  let successResponse = false
  try {
    console.log(context.type)
    if (context.type != 'ui') return
    console.log(context.fieldChanged)
    if (context.fieldChanged != 'total') return
    const locale = context.user.getNativeLocale()
    console.log(locale)
    const response = https.get(`./taxFormula/${locale}`)
    console.log(response)
    if (response.code[0] != '2') return
    const formula = JSON.parse(response.body).taxRule
    console.log(formula)
    const tax = getTaxInfo(context, formula)
    console.log(tax)
    context.record.update('tax_info', tax)
    successResponse = true
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  } finally {
    return successResponse
  }

because there are many undocumented behaviors with the API that I am working with. I need typescript to keep track of the various idiosyncrasies which I record in a .d.ts file. However, the console.logs everywhere make for clunky code, and I find myself thinking, what if I could just do this:
function updateTaxRecord(context: updateTaxRecordContext): boolean {
  let successResponse = false
  try {
    if (context.type.l('type') != 'ui') return
    if (context.fieldChanged.l('fieldChanged') return
    const locale = context.user.getNativeLocale().l('locale')
    const response = https.get(`./taxFormula/${locale}`).l('response')
    if (response.code[0] != '2') return
    const formula = JSON.parse(response.body).taxRule.l('formula')
    const tax = getTaxInfo(context, formula).l('tax')
    context.record.update('tax_info', tax)
    successResponse = true
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  } finally {
    return successResponse
  }

which is significantly more precise. Plus, I could just forget about logging while I am writing the code and write a vim macro at the end to match the const then yank the variable name and add the .l at the end.
What I have tried is
interface Object {
    l(title: string): any
}

and in a .d.ts file
declare global {
    interface Object {
        l(title: string): any
    }
}

These did not remove the error.
I am looking to get it working and not a lecture on what good/clean code looks like. For context, I am writing server-side javascript/typescript that is not in Node.js and I have timed scripts and found no difference in how long the script runs when Object.prototype is modified. I am open to a JsDoc solution if that is what it takes. I saw that there were slightly similar questions asked here, but they did not actually solve the issue.

function (title: string) => { is a syntax error.

How about a util function that doesn't modify the global object prototype? const l = <T>(v: T): T => { console.log(v); return v; } and if (l(context.type) !== "ui") return;

• Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] without typos. We should be able to copy and paste it into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing. You should test it in an IDE yourself (there's no way you've actually got function (title: string) => { in your own code. • You say you've already tried declaration merging and it didn't work. I can't reproduce this. That means it's something specific to your project or version of TypeScript or the way you're importing things, and the code you've presented is unfortunately not a [mre]. Without that, we can't help too much.

(See prev comment) • "I am looking to get it working and not a lecture on what good/clean code looks like." You're going to get such a lecture in any responsible answer, even if it goes on to explain how to get it working. Stack Overflow is supposed to be a Q/A for future readers too, and they should know why not to mess with native prototypes, even if you're not interested in hearing it.  Feel free to ignore the lecture when it comes, of course.

"changes I make to the Object.prototype" - please don't. Though if you really have to, at least make them non-enumerable!

You should extend Object interface by d.ts file:
// global.d.ts
interface Object {
  l<T>(this: T, title: string): T
}

and properly define type for l function in the code:
// some.js
/**
 * @template T
 * @this {T}
 * @param {string} title 
 * @returns {T}
 */
Object.prototype.l = function(title) {
  console.log({ [title]: this })
  return this
};

({name: "foo"}).l("name").name;
Function.l("bind").bind;

